# How to set environment variables in pyenv?

Tags: python, linux, virtualenv, pyenv

I'm using `pyenv`. The environment is created with these commands:

```
pyenv install 3.6.0
pyenv virtualenv 3.6.0 foo
pyenv local foo

python my_app.py
```

In the application I want to load some environment variables with this command:

```
SOME_VARIABLE = environ.get('MY_ENV_VAR', None)
```

The problem is, that although `MY_ENV_VAR` is set with `export MY_ENV_VAR=test` (and I can display its content with `echo $MY_ENV_VAR`), the python code reads no value.

So how can this be done correctly?

Comment: Can you compare `echo $MY_ENV_VAR` and `python -c "import os; print(os.environ.get('MY_ENV_VAR'))"`; do both print "test"?

Comment: @jasdhfiu-asef-aesf-asef-a-sgaa No I didn't, what should it do? I don't use pipenv. Didn't you mean `pyenv shell`? This gives "no shell-specific version configured". @phd echoing the variable returns its true content, priting it in python like this prints "None".

Answer (score 0):

What IDE/Editor are you using? I am guessing the variable is not added into the same environment.

If you use a code editor like vscode you need to activate the environment then from **the same terminal** add the variable to the environment and then run the script.

```
# my_app.py
from os import environ

SOME_VARIABLE2 = environ.get('MY_ENV_VAR',None)
print(SOME_VARIABLE2)

SOME_VARIABLE = environ['MY_ENV_VAR']
print(SOME_VARIABLE)
```

```sh
# vscode terminal

test on main [?] via  v3.8.6 (foo) 
❯source foo/bin/activate
❯export MY_ENV_VAR=test
❯ python my_app.py         
test
test
```